# Moving code inside a function is not working

Tags: javascript, function, nested-loops

Any help will be very appreciated... I am trying to figure out how to nest loops inside of a function. If I input this into the console...

```
var i, arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
var remove = [];
for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (Number(arr[i]) != i % 2) {
            remove.push(arr[i]);
            arr.splice(i, 1);
        }
    }
console.log(remove);
```

it returns with the desired array, removing all the even numbers from arr. But, if I wrap it in a function, it is undefined...

```
var i, arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
var remove = [];

function reject() {

    for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (Number(arr[i]) != i % 2) {
            remove.push(arr[i]);
            arr.splice(i, 1);
        }
    }
};


console.log(remove);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The function is never called. See this example - http://jsfiddle.net/hhpbqcqh/

Comment: Oh my god! I've spent hours on this! Thank-you so much for the heads up!

Comment: What is undefined? You can learn more about functions in a JavaScript tutorial: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When code is not in a function, every line in the script is executed as it is interpreted (roughly speaking).

If you wrap some code inside a function, you have to **call the function** for it's effects to be applied.

Also, you should try and keep some variables inside the function, for example your `i` counter could be local to the function instead of the global scope of the function.

Therefore, use the function name to apply it's effects:

```
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
var remove = [];

function reject() {
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (Number(arr[i]) != i % 2) {
            remove.push(arr[i]);
            arr.splice(i, 1);
        }
    }
};

reject(); // Difference here, we're calling the function.
console.log(remove);
```

Comment: I meant to thank-you earlier... I'm still a newbie and some of these basics can take hours to spot. I appreciate your response.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the function before you try to log the value of remove.

```
var i, arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], remove = [];
function reject() {
    for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (Number(arr[i]) != i % 2) {
            remove.push(arr[i]);
            arr.splice(i, 1);
        }
    }
};
reject();
console.log(remove);
```

Answer (score 0):

Others have already answered what the problem is, you have to call the function. However, if you improve it not to use globals, it may be more obvious that you need to call it and is much cleaner code.

```
var arr = [1,2,3,4,5];
function reject(input) {
    var output = []; 
    for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
        if (Number(arr[i]) != i % 2) {
            output.push(arr[i]);
            input.splice(i, 1);
        }
    }
    return output;
};
var remove = reject(arr);
```